# YARD doc - how to document a class type focusing on its parent class

Tags: code-documentation, yard

Suppose I have the following

```rb
class AbstractClass; end
class ConcreteClass1 < AbstractClass; end
class ConcreteClass2 < AbstractClass; end
```

How do I document a return value that returns a class instance of a class that inherits AbstractClass (either ConcreteClass1 or ConcreteClass2) ? I want to focus on the fact that the return value can be either `ConcreteClass1` or `ConcreteClass2` but what matters is that they are all `kind_of(AbstractClass)`

I was thinking of something like this, is it the good approach ?

```rb
# Class MyClassFactory implements the factory pattern for selecting the appropriate class for xxx
def MyClassFactory
  # @return [? < AbstractClass] an instance of a class inheriting AbstractClass
  def create_instance(*args)
     if cond?
       ConcreteClass1
     else
       ConcreteClass2
     end.new(*args)
  end
end
```

Now suppose my method returns the class itself, and not a class instance, would this be the good approach ?

```rb
def MyClassFactory
  # @return [? <= AbstractClass] the class to be used
  def select_class
     if cond?
       ConcreteClass1
     else
       ConcreteClass2
     end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sufficient to write

```
# @return [AbstractClass]
```

The reader should assume that Liskov substitution may apply. The `Abstract` prefix (as well as an [@abstract](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#abstract) tag) will also communicate this clearly, and the resulting documentation will list `ConcreteClass1` and `ConcreteClass2` under the "Direct Known Subclasses" of `AbstractClass`.

As for returning a class, the YARD creator's [recommendation](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/1109#issuecomment-322071576) is to use `Class<AbstractClass>`.